# Proof Regarding an iff Statement

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a function.

Then $f$ is one-to-one iff for all subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, $f(A\cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Any proofs or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Begin by examining simple examples.  Let $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$, $Y = \{y_1, y_2, y_3\}$, $A = \{x_1, x_2\}$, $B = \{x_2, x_3\}$.  First, consider
$$
f(x_{k}) = y_{k}, \quad k = 1, 2, 3.
$$
Is it 1-to-1?  Does it preserve intersections?

Now, what about
$$
f(x_1) = f(x_2) = y_1, \quad f(x_{3}) = y_3 ?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incomplete proof of the --> part of the biconditional

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint for one side:

If $f$ is not one-to-one then $X$ has two *distinct* elements $u,v$ with $f(u)=f(v)$.

Now let $A$ and $B$ both be specific singletons and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In case your question in on the logical method :  Different ways to prove an iff statement.

With : 
Proposition A = f is a one to one function

Proposition B = for all subsets ... the image of the intersection under f is the intersection of the images of the subsets.

(1) Prove A -> B

(2) Prove B -->A

(3) Conclude : A <--> B

---

(1) Prove A -> B

(2) Prove ~A --> ~B

(3) Use contraposition : on (2) : B --> A

(4) Conclude : A <--> B

---

(1) Suppose A is true and that B is false ( or the inverse: A false, B true) that is suppose : ~ (A <--> B)

(3) Derive a contradiction.

(3) Conclude that : (A <--> B)

---